# Remove duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql

How can I remove the duplicate rows? I have joined two tables now I'm getting duplicate data.

Comment: `select distinct`? You should at least provide sample data and the query you use so we do not guess trying to help you.

Comment: Try reading this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp). This is about @PavelSmirnov answer.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  What does the data look like?  What does the query look like?  It could be an issue with your join criteria, or it could be actual duplicates in the data in which case you'll need DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous comments, a little bit more complex answer will be construction with PARTITION and ROW_NUMBER

`select * from (select *, row_number() over (partition by <duplicate_field> order by <duplicate_field>) as rn from <table>) where rn=1`